# when select clause return empty result "INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE" can't clean table

Tags: insert, hiveql, overwrite

1. create table

   create external table test_overwrite(
       t_id bigint,t_name string
       ) STORED AS TEXTFILE;
       location '/user/hive/test_overwrite'
2. insert one record

   insert into test_overwrite select 1, "test" from (select count(*) from test_overwrite ) a;

   ```
   +----------------------+------------------------+
   | test_overwrite.t_id  | test_overwrite.t_name  |
   +----------------------+------------------------+
   | 1                    | test                   |
   +----------------------+------------------------+
   1 row selected (0.538 seconds)
   ```
3. overwrite with new record

   ```
   insert overwrite table test_overwrite select 2,"good";



   +----------------------+------------------------+
   | test_overwrite.t_id  | test_overwrite.t_name  |
   +----------------------+------------------------+
   | 2                    | good                   |
   +----------------------+------------------------+
   1 row selected (0.619 seconds)
   ```
4. Failed to overwrite table with empty result.

   ```
   insert overwrite table test_overwrite select 2,"good" from test_overwrite where t_id > 5;

   +----------------------+------------------------+
   | test_overwrite.t_id  | test_overwrite.t_name  |
   +----------------------+------------------------+
   | 2                    | good                   |
   +----------------------+------------------------+
   1 row selected (0.619 seconds)
   ```

question: does anyone know how to fix the problem?